# How to make a datagridview the same to another form's datagridview in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, oop

So when I click a button on Form1, it should copy the datagridview's values to form2's datagridview's values.

Here is some of my code:

```
while ((asd = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {

                string[] elements = asd.Split(';');

                if (checkBox1.Checked == false)
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                        elements[i] = elements[i].Trim(new char[] { ' ', '"' });

                    erDataSet1.Eredmenyek.AddEredmenyekRow(elements[0], elements[1], elements[2],0,00.00);
                }

                else
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                        elements[i] = elements[i].Trim(new char[] { ' ', '"' });

                    erDataSet1.Eredmenyek.AddEredmenyekRow(elements[0], elements[1], elements[2],Convert.ToDouble(elements[3]), Convert.ToDouble(elements[4]));

                }


            }
            sr.Close();
```

Button that shows on datagridview:

```
private void button6_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgv1.DataSource = erDataSet1.Eredmenyek;

    }
```

and on form2 button that doesnt work:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgver.DataSource = erDataSet1.Eredmenyek;
    }
```

Comment: what is your datagridviews datasource.

Comment: Now I've created a dataset, its working on form1, but not on form2.

Answer (score 2):

You might look instead at [implementing virtual mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b177d6d.aspx) on your `DataGridView` controls, and then passing around a reference to your data source.  Duplicating the rows themselves is a bit of hack in most circumstances.

Comment: Huh Im too beginner for this code.